# XML when statement doesn't work

Tags: xslt

The following is giving me the "memberstable is an unexpected token" error.

```
 <xsl:when value-of memberstable/@member_cancontactthem =1>
       <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
          <xsl:value-of select="You can contact this member"/></td>
        </xsl:when>
```

I've used this to initialize it:

```
<xsl: value of select = "memberstable/@member_cancontactthem" />
```

The value in the DB is boolean, so either 1 or 0.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you are missing the `select=` attribute and quotes?

Comment: So
<xsl:when value-of select= "memberstable/@member_cancontactthem =1">
?

Comment: `<xsl:when value-of select="memberstable[@member_cancontactthem=1]">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now, all suggestions will produce errors if I am not mistaken. `xsl:when` needs a `test` attribute:

```
<xsl:when test="memberstable[@member_cancontactthem='1']">
```

is the correct syntax. Also, `xsl:when` must be inside an `xsl:choose` element.

In general, please be *careful* with whitespace, and with hyphenations (for instance, `value of` is not the same as `value-of`) and make sure all attribute values are between quotes. XSLT must respect the rules of XML, which is not as forgiving as HTML.

Comment: Ah apologies, I thought that the "test" on most examples out there was just a random variable. 
This worked, thank you for the explanation.